# Detect crashs of invoked dlls called from .NET

Tags: .net, delphi, pinvoke, dllimport, invoke

I've some native dlls (Delphi) that I invoke from a .NET application.
If there occur any type of crash in the DLL the whole .NET application crashes. How can I prevent this and ensure, that the .NET application doesn't crash and recognize the error. I don't need the specific error-feedback from the native dll (which is impossible, since it crashed). But I want to write something to my .NET log files like "xyz.dll crashed".

Is this possible P/Invoking a (Delphi or C++)dll from .NET?

Comment: Depending on the type of the assembly (if they are not OCX for example but "business oriented" objects), you could register them in COM+ and declare the COM+ Application as a "server" application. In this case you will be able to gracefully handle crashes in these components. This can have impact on performance and security configuration though... see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973484.aspx (Application Recycling and Process Dump chapters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would happen if your DLL threw exceptions out of its exported functions. A DLL must not do that so you need to catch all exceptions at the boundary of your DLL, and convert them into error code return values.

If you don't have control over the DLL then you'll need to write a wrapper layer to it. Create another native DLL which calls the original DLL and catch any exceptions that it throws. You could do this with another Delphi DLL I suspect, or alternatively with a C or C++ DLL that used SEH to catch the exceptions.

It would be possible to script the generation of the code for such a wrapper DLL. You'd want to do that if there were a lot of functions that you needed to wrap.

Answer (score 3):

All entry points in the Delphi DLL must be placed in a try...except block and return a value (int) to the .NET side indicating whether the call completed with or without errors.